# calculate number of months between 2 dates

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two datetime

```
fd= np.datetime64('2008-04-14')
sd = np.datetime64('2012-01-14')
res = fd- sd
```

and the output of res is numpy.timedelta64(2601,'D')

How do I get the number of months?

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify the unit in which you want the output while declaring the dates. As you want it in months, use `M` as the unit parameter.

```
fd = np.datetime64('2012-01-14', 'M') 
sd = np.datetime64('2008-04-14', 'M')
res = fd - sd
```

Output:
`numpy.timedelta64(45,'M')`
To get the integral part of the answer:
`int(res)`
Output: `45`

To get the answer as a string:
`str(res)`
Output: `'45 months'`

Comment: how do I add a month to a date?

Comment: when I used for your code, and add a month to the date, it removes the day

Comment: Do you want both the number of days and the number of months?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def months(d1, d2):
    return d1.month - d2.month + 12*(d1.year - d2.year)

d1 = datetime.strptime('2008-04-14', '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime.strptime('2012-01-14', '%Y-%m-%d')

print(months(d2, d1))
```

Output:

```
45
```

Answer (score 0):

A *numpythonic* version:

```
monthNo = (sd.astype('M8[M]') - fd.astype('M8[M]')).astype(int)
```

Or a *pandasonic* version:

```
monthNo = (pd.Period(value=sd, freq='M') - pd.Period(value=fd, freq='M')).n
```

In both cases for your data the result is:

```
45
```